# If Value is Equal to Anchor's Text then Change it's CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle 1 = http://liveweave.com/gG4EHH
Fiddle 2 = http://jsbin.com/zequyilo/1/edit

I have a set of anchors that I click to change a selected elements CSS (In this case the font-family attribute)

What I'm trying to do is type the font in a textbox and if the font is one of the fonts in the anchor list to change it's css according to the text.

I'd like to use a method of something like this where if the input value is equal to the anchor's text to change it's css, but not exactly sure on how to go about it.

```
$('.grab-font-family').on('keyup change', function() {
  $('.grab-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  if ( $('.grab-typography a').text() === $(this).val() ) {
     $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
  }
});
```

I tried this method using the title attribute, but when I tried `arial black`, or `andale mono` the anchor that has that title. it's background was not changed.

```
$('.grab-font-family').on('keyup change', function() {
  $('.grab-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $(".grab-typography a[title=" + $(this).val() + "]").css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
});
```

So I tried using the contains selector. If I type `a` in the textbox this methos will change all the anchor's background colors that begin with an `a`.

```
$('.grab-font-family').on('keyup change', function() {
  $('.grab-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $(".grab-typography a:contains(" + $(this).val() + ")").css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter()` is the most controllable way. Your first approach is only pulling the `text()` of first element in the collection. This is the same for all `getters` when there are more than one element in the collection.

`filter()` will loop over all elements and let you run more involved conditions

Make sure to quote fonts that have spaces in them or they will be misinterpreted by browser

```
$('.grab-font-family').on('keyup change', function() {
  var font=this.value;
  $('.grab-typography a').filter(function(){
     return this.title === font;/* return ones that match font */
  }).css('font-family', '"'+font+'"'});
})
```

Comment: I so wish I knew about filter before hand. This is a very handy handler. Mucho gracias - http://liveweave.com/9CE1Xp